# MapKit JS - Have Map Fit Height/Width of Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working with MapKit JS for the first time and using the [Custom Callout example](https://developer.apple.com/maps/web/) from the Apple website. I'm trying to get the map to resize automatically to fit the size of the browser window but am getting stuck with this.

I can see there is a CSS style for the map `height: 600px` which presumably is the reason why the map is leaving an empty white space as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I've tried adjusting this to `height: 100%` which results in a blank page and can't work out the syntax to get the map to show in the whole window regardless of the size of the window.

Here's the full code from the Apple example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js"></script>

  <style>
    #map {
      height: 600px;
    }
    
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      color: #2aaef5;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .landmark {
      width: 250px;
      padding: 7px 0 0 0;
      background: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.75);
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0 10px;
      transform-origin: 0 10px;
    }
    
    .landmark h1 {
      margin-top: 0;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      background: #2aaef5;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .landmark section {
      padding: 0 15px 5px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .landmark section p {
      margin: 5px 0;
    }
    
    .landmark:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 7px;
      left: -13px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      margin-bottom: -13px;
      border-right: 13px solid #2aaef5;
      border-top: 13px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      border-bottom: 13px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes scale-and-fadein {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes scale-and-fadein {
      0% {
        transform: scale(0.2);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>
    mapkit.init({
      authorizationCallback: function(done) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "/services/jwt");
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
          done(this.responseText);
        });
        xhr.send();
      }
    });

    // Landmarks data
    var sanFranciscoLandmarks = [{
        coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7951315, -122.402986),
        title: "Transamerica Pyramid",
        phone: "+1-415-983-5420",
        url: "http://www.transamericapyramidcenter.com/"
      },
      {
        coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7954201, -122.39352),
        title: "Ferry Building",
        phone: "+1 (415) 983-8030",
        url: "http://www.ferrybuildingmarketplace.com"
      },
      {
        coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8083396, -122.415727),
        title: "Fisherman's Wharf",
        phone: "+1 (415) 673-3530",
        url: "http://visitfishermanswharf.com"
      },
      {
        coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8023553, -122.405742),
        title: "Coit Tower",
        phone: "+1 (415) 249-0995",
        url: "http://sfrecpark.org/destination/telegraph-hill-pioneer-park/coit-tower/"
      },
      {
        coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7552305, -122.452624),
        title: "Sutro Tower",
        phone: "+1 (415) 681-8850",
        url: "http://www.sutrotower.com"
      },
      {
        coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.779267, -122.419269),
        title: "City Hall",
        phone: "+1 (415) 701-2311",
        url: "http://sfgsa.org/index.aspx?page=1085"
      },
      {
        coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8184493, -122.478409),
        title: "Golden Gate Bridge",
        phone: "+1 (415) 921-5858",
        url: "http://www.goldengatebridge.org"
      },
      {
        coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7785538, -122.514035),
        title: "Cliff House",
        phone: "+1 (415) 386-3330",
        url: "http://www.cliffhouse.com/"
      }
    ];

    // Landmark annotation callout delegate
    var CALLOUT_OFFSET = new DOMPoint(-148, -78);
    var landmarkAnnotationCallout = {
      calloutElementForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
        return calloutForLandmarkAnnotation(annotation);
      },

      calloutAnchorOffsetForAnnotation: function(annotation, element) {
        return CALLOUT_OFFSET;
      },

      calloutAppearanceAnimationForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
        return ".4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5) 0s 1 normal scale-and-fadein";
      }
    };

    // Landmarks annotations
    var annotations = sanFranciscoLandmarks.map(function(landmark) {
      var annotation = new mapkit.MarkerAnnotation(landmark.coordinate, {
        callout: landmarkAnnotationCallout,
        color: "#c969e0"
      });
      annotation.landmark = landmark;
      return annotation;
    });

    var map = new mapkit.Map("map");
    map.showItems(annotations);

    // Landmark annotation custom callout
    function calloutForLandmarkAnnotation(annotation) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "landmark";

      var title = div.appendChild(document.createElement("h1"));
      title.textContent = annotation.landmark.title;

      var section = div.appendChild(document.createElement("section"));

      var phone = section.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
      phone.className = "phone";
      phone.textContent = annotation.landmark.phone;

      var link = section.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
      link.className = "homepage";
      var a = link.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
      a.href = annotation.landmark.url;
      a.textContent = "website";

      return div;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use view height (vh) in the map id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the style as follows resolved this for me:

```
<style>
  #map {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
  }
  body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
 </style>
```